# How can I check if an array contains a specific key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arrayiterator

I know how to check for a value in an array, but how do I check for a value in an Array Iterator?

```
$array = new ArrayIterator(array(
'1QmRjtsw2UQ' => array('pubdate' => '26 Jun 15', 'alt' => '8 Year Old Beautifully Covers Thinking Out Loud', 'anchor text' => '8-yo \'Thinking Out Loud\''),
'eKqLaYrcf3A' => array('pubdate' => '25 Jun 15', 'alt' => 'Plane Lands On Truck', 'anchor text' => 'Plane Lands On Truck'),
));
```

I'm trying to check for the values such as `1QmRjtsw2UQ`.

This does not work:

```
if(in_array('1QmRjtsw2UQ', $array));
```

Comment: because you've created an arrayiterator, you've actually got an object which has methods and properties. what you need to do is a loop over the elements and make a comparison against the returned values.

Answer (score 6):

why don't you use [**array_key_exists**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) ?

```
if(array_key_exists('1QmRjtsw2UQ', $array)) 
{
      // do something
}
```

--- 2024-03-08---

Above solution works only if 2nd argument is an **array** as of `PHP >=8`

If second argument is an **object** then above solution is deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0, and removed as of PHP 8.0.0.

To check whether a property exists in an object, use `property_exists()` function refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Comment: This works and makes more sense than using `$array->offsetExists('1QmRjtsw2UQ');`

Comment: In PHP7 work, in PHP8: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, ArrayIterator given in ...

Comment: @RobertMáslo.  :  you're right this behaviour is deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0, and removed as of PHP 8.0.0.

To check whether a property exists in an object, `property_exists()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$array->offsetExists('1QmRjtsw2UQ');
```